# I want to extract ALL frames from a 30fps frames (so 30 frames per 1 second of video) using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, extract, video-processing

I am new to using ffmpeg, but I need to extract all frames of a short (<10 second) video while maintaining the quality. Does anyone have code for this?

I have tried using:

C:\Users\taylo>ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 %04d.png

But it could not find my video anyway (it was stored in the downloads folder).

**EDIT**:
I fixed this problem by setting my directory to my Videos folder (Windows 11) and putting my "test_video.mp4" in that folder.

```
C:\Users\(name)\>cd .\Videos
```

I am currently using two lines of code to extract these frames:

```
C:\Users\(name)\Videos>ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -r 30/1 out%03d.png
```

AND

```
C:\Users\(name)\Videos>ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 out%03d.png
```

Does anyone know the difference between the two? I extracted a 4 second video at 30 fps and figured I would get ~120 frames but am getting slightly more at ~145 with both methods. I'm assuming this is accounting for milliseconds?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the video inside FFmpeg folder. Copy this code inside a .bat file in the same folder and run it:

```
echo off
mkdir outputs
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" "outputs\%%~na %%03d.png"
pause
```

This would extract the frames of all the .mp4 files available inside the FFmpeg folder, to a folder called "outputs" in the same directory; with the PNG format. The name of each file would be in this format: "source name 000.png".
For a 2 seconds long video with 15 fps, this code created 30 PNG files (2x15=30).